# Structure menu link is wrong after use command "drush rr"

Tags: views, drush

[image]

I changed structure some folder module then use command "drush rr" to registry rebuild modules but get a trouble look like picture:
 - Link "add new view","import" and "settings" not inside link "Views"

Comment: Any errors in your logs?

Comment: I don't see any errors.